# Classloader issue while using template outside the portlet

Tags: liferay

I have written .tmpl files for email sending functionality in Liferay.
I have kept all the files inside the portlet and it is working fine.
I am using `ContentUtil.get(String location)` method to read the file.

Now I need to move all the files in the server. I am thinking to create one folder inside data folder and place all the files into that folder.
But I am getting below errors if i use `ContentUtil.get(String location)`:

```
11:24:54,619 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-30][ContentUtil:64] java.io.IOException: Unable to open resource in class loader C:/Users/../Desktop/.../liferay-portal-6.1.20-ee-ga2/data/templates/ABC/client/email_client_add_request_subject.tmpl
```

Can anyone suggest me the best way to remove all the files from portlet and place it inside server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message is already explaining, `ContentUtil` is used for reading from the classpath. To read a file from the file system you could use `FileUtil`:

```
FileUtil.read(new File(PropsValues.LIFERAY_HOME + "/data/templates/..."));
```